# How to use Web.config to configure SMTPClients in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, web-config, smtpclient

I'm trying to wrap my head around the Web.configs `<mailSettings>`

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp from="abc@abc.com">
      <network host="127.0.0.1" userName="username" password="password" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164240 `from` is used to "specify the from adress for outgoing e-mails", but when I create a `new MailMessage` it requires a From-adress.
According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc.aspx `SmtpClient.Send` should throw an error if `MailMessage.From = null`.

Could someone please tell me the best practice for configurating the SMTP-Client through the Web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the documentation for the configuration section here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164240(v=vs.110).aspx

In regards to the `from` attribute, if you create the `MailMessage` using the default constructor (i.e. `new MailMessage()`), then it will use whatever is specified in the `from` attribute as the from address.